# Facebook PHP SDK getAccessToken always returns blank

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm using the code provided by Facebook SDK, but it doesn't work because it always returns blank for accesstoken. I've setup the correct app id and secret keys.

But it does give me `[FBRLH_state] => 8013d8cb8ebc0fc5af09fd141dd13b1e` which I don't understand yet.

```
<?php

session_start();
require_once("functions.php");

require_once ROOT_PATH . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Facebook\Facebook;
use Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException;
use Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException;

// Init PHP Sessions
session_start();

try {
    $fb = new Facebook([
      'app_id' => FB_APP_ID,
      'app_secret' => FB_APP_SECRET
    ]);

} catch (Exception $e) {
    $message = 'Caught new Facebook: '.$e->getMessage();
    $result2=0;
}
echo "<pre>";print_r($message);echo "</pre>";


if (!isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
    $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = null;
}

if (!$_SESSION['facebook_access_token']) {
    echo "not facebook_access_token <br />";
    try {   
        $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $message = 'Caught getRedirectLoginHelper2: '.$e->getMessage();
        $result2=0;
    }

    try {
        echo "try facebook_access_token <br />";
        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $helper->getAccessToken();

    } catch(FacebookResponseException $e) {
        // When Graph returns an error
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    } catch(FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($_SESSION);
echo "</pre>";

if ($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']) {
    echo "You are logged in!";
} else {
    $permissions = ['ads_management'];
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://xxxx/vendor/', $permissions);
    echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook</a>';
} 

?>
```

Comment: Perhaps this official example might help: https://developers.intern.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login/5.0.0, maybe update the SDK to 5 to get latest bug fixes.

Comment: use the full example